# How to run task inside onCreate

Tags: android, runnable, worker

I'm new to Android and threading.

I'm just testing things right now so I read not to do intensive tasks in main thread so I put my method inside onCreate and the method is run in a Runnable which is a task that another thread will run if that is correct and anyways I noticed when I launch app, I get a black screen and screen freezes but no "app is not responding" message.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
     boolean isFooMethodDone = false;

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //foo(); //MISTAKE: I meant to start run method which calls foo() 
        startTask();

    }

     public void foo ( ) {
           System.out.println("I should be printed only once!");
            int sum = 0;

           while ( sum < 1000 ) {
               sum += 0.2;
           }
          }

      Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

        volatile boolean stopMe = false;
        volatile boolean isBlahMethodStarted = false;

        @Override
        public void run() {

             if ( isBlahMethodStarted == false ) {
                  foo();
                  isBlahMethodStarted = true;
              }

            if ( isFooMethodDone == true )
                stopMe = true;

            if (stopMe) {
                stopTask();
            }
        }
    };

    void startTask() {
        myRunnable.run();
    }

    void stopTask() {
        mHandler.removeCallbacks( myRunnable );
    }
       }

    }
```

**COMMENTS FROM HERE ADDED ON JUNE 14 2017:** Can I add a handler inside run to tell it to run my blah() method and sleep a bit so that it doesn't keep blocking main thread so see block comments on needing help on how to do this because it's the while loop causing not letting
main thread have control, I reposted Runnable nested class and foo method below again because below I did put in a Handler last line in while loop in run method:

```
public void foo ( ) {
       System.out.println("I should be printed only once!");
        int sum = 0;

       while ( sum < 1000 ) {
           sum += 0.2;
       }
     isFooMethodDone = true;
      }

Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

volatile boolean stopMe = false;
volatile boolean isBlahMethodStarted = false;

@Override
public void run() {

     if ( isBlahMethodStarted == false ) {
          /*For foo method below, how do I add a handler or thread to tell 
          foo() to run and then
          sleep a bit to let give control back to main thread so that I 
          don't get black screen which is main thread waiting and then app 
          freezes*/
          foo();
          isBlahMethodStarted = true;
      }

    if ( isFooMethodDone == true )
        stopMe = true;

    if (stopMe) {
        stopTask();
    }
    else
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
}
```

Comment: Look up how to use `AsyncTask`.

Comment: You should attach the Runnable to the Handler

Comment: Please explain, I thought handler was only when you need to communicate with main thread whenever the worker thread is accessing GUI objects like ImageViews, TextViews etc.

Comment: Please someone check my new comments in my OP added on June 14 2017 so see the block comment just above foo method called in the run method.

Answer (score 0):

Well nothing happens because all you did was call the foo method. So the app appears frozen as the program waits for the foo method to finish executing before responding to any input. To avoid this, you would want to put foo in your runnable, and execute the runnable in your onCreate(); This way the time consuming loop in foo won't freeze up your main thread (UI thread), and the app will be responsive.

Comment: Oh, that was a typo! But still no, I still get a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out!

## Explanation

A worker thread will call my blah method again and not just once so I changed the while loop to an if to let control be given back to main thread and I changed the int sum var to a static var to ensure the blah method will stop so:

```
public void foo ( ) {
   System.out.println("I should be printed only once!");

   if ( sum < 1000 ) {//int sum is declared and initialized as static var
    //outside any classes
       sum += 0.2;
   }
 isFooMethodDone = true;
  }
```

Thanks, Bawb, myself!